# How to let AVPlayer play multiple items?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, avfoundation

I'm trying to play multiple mp3's with `AVPlayer`. I fetch URLs of the mp3's and then let `AVPlayer`plays them one by one.

My first attempt is letting a single `AVPlayer`plays all the mp3's with `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem` method. But there is no sound except for the first song.

When I try to generate `AVPlayer` for every single item, and let each `AVPlayer` plays its item, the app works as I wished.

My question is, is `AVPlayer` designed to play a single item? If I don't want to allocate a new `AVPlayer` for each item, I have to use `AVQueuePlayer` to play multiple items, right? Which method is preferred?

Comment: Is your target Mac OS X or iOS? You’ve specified tags for both.

Comment: Mac OS X Lion and iOS 4 all have AV Foundation supports now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AVQueuePlayer` works perfectly for this case. It'll remove played items automatically.